# Can variant data type store fixed length string data type values in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

As per the [official Microsoft.com documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/variant-data-type):

> A Variant is a special data type that can contain any kind of data except fixed-length String data. (Variant types now support user-defined types.) A Variant can also contain the special values Empty, Error, Nothing, and Null. You can determine how the data in a Variant is treated by using the VarType function or TypeName function.

I just need to understand why below code is working when variant cannot store fixed length strings?

```
Sub Test()

    Dim y As Variant
    Dim x As String * 10
    y = x
    MsgBox y

End Sub
```

Comment: `You can determine how the data in a Variant is treated by using the VarType function or TypeName function.` The clue is in the highlighted text. Add `MsgBox VarType(y)` before `y = x` and add  `MsgBox VarType(y)` again after  `y = x`

Answer (score 3):

The `y = x` casts the fixed length string into a normal string like `x = 10` would cast that number into a string. Test it with `y = x & "123456789012345"` and you will see it is not fixed length anymore.

```
Sub Test()    
    Dim y As Variant
    Dim x As String * 10
    y = x
    MsgBox y    

    'but this works too
    y = x & "123456789012345"
    MsgBox y    
End Sub
```

That means `x` is a fixed length string but `y` is not fixed in length anymore. If you do not explicitly convert one type into another VBA implicitly casts them into the other type if possible (if not you get a type mismatch).

That means for example that you can push a number into a string without explicitly converting it:

```
Dim str As String
str = 12345
```

will cast the number `12345` into a string like `str = CStr(12345)`.

Similar happens when you push a fixed length string into a variant. It implicitly casts into a non fixed length string.

Answer (score 2):

When `String * 10` is cast to Variant, the Variant becomes a string. Check the `y` in the Watch window:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim y As Variant
    Dim x As String * 10        
    x = "12345678900"
    y = x
    y = "12345678900"        
    Debug.Print y

End Sub
```

[image]